# Software to test FAT Implementation

Tags: testing, filesystems, fat32, fat

Do you know any software to verify a FAT Implementation?
I'm writing on a FAT32 Implementation which supports "basic wear leveling" on a SPI-Flash.

Now I want to know if my (binary) Image of the Flash is a "valid" FAT, maybe including a list of the FAT BootArea Parameters.

OS independent, tied to Windows on Work, but have my Linux Machine available.

If you know any software - perfect! Let me know!
If not - don't worry, thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have binary image then run any disk check tool and see analyse the output. some of those tools may require you to mount the image so this will probably be much easier on linux. another test you can do is to: mount, install an OS on this image and then run it with virtualbox to check if the system boots correctly

Comment: I couldn't find any which allows to 'open'/look into a binary. For your second option: Whole Flash Storage is 8MB and connected to a STM32 running FreeRTOS. I doubt i want to install another OS inside that :D

Comment: i would use standard linux `fsck` (with `mount` if needed). FreeRTOS is an OS. if it boots correctly, that's a smoke test

Comment: I would upvote you but i'm still a rookie so i can't, thanks anyway. FreeRTOS IS a OS, but not installed on any FS but in ASM on the STM internal Flash. The Flash in the spotlight is an external flash accessed by the FreeRTOS

Comment: if you don't need the boot feature on your flash then you don't have to test it. if you want test it: you have FAT implementation, right? use that implementation to create bigger image. you can also install some small OS at 8mb disk just for the testing phase